# Best way to display two call to actions in a single column

Tags: buttons, call-to-action, column

Currently the users can "print codes" for the entire group or "invite individuals"  by email.

Can you imagine a better solution to make it more clear that both options are available without prioritizing one OR splitting it into 2 columns?

[image: list]

Comment: The first line of text already makes it clear that both options are available. I suggest that you actually create a call-to-action button that looks similar to Print codes and reveal the input fields when the user clicks on it. Is there are reason why you don't want prioritize or split into 2 columns?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe would you use something like apple scope bar?

[image: applescopebar]

[image]